# Is it possible to make the Tokenizer namespace aware (when using Splitter)

Tags: xml, apache-camel, xml-namespaces

We have an application where we are processing very large xml files (3GB+). For splitting we use the Tokenizer. The xml's we receive have different namespace prefixes or use no prefix at all. Is it possible for the Tokenizer to handle this? 
The only thing I found was inheriting the default namespace with the inheritNamespaceTagName attribute, but unfortunately it doesn't work when namespace prefixes are used.

Thanks for your help!

Sample 1:

```
<foo:orders xmnls:foo="http://foo.com">
  <foo:order id="1">Camel in Action</order>
  <foo:order id="1">ActiveMQ in Action</order>
  <foo:order id="1">DSL in Action</order>
</foo:orders>
```

Sample 2:

```
<bar:orders xmnls:foo="http://foo.com">
  <bar:order id="1">Camel in Action</order>
  <bar:order id="1">ActiveMQ in Action</order>
  <bar:order id="1">DSL in Action</order>
</bar:orders>
```

Our route:

```
 <route id="orderProcessorRoute">
      <from uri="file:process-xml?delete=true"/>
      <split streaming="true">
          <tokenize token="order" xml="true"/>
          <to uri="bean:xmlParseBean"/>
          <to uri="vm:orderAggregator"/>
      </split>
     <to uri="file:backup"/>
 </route>
```

Comment: You should look into extended vtd-xml and use that to split XML documents upto 256 gb in size.

Answer (score 2):

See the option inheritNamespaceTagName, documented at: http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html. So in your case it should be:

```
<tokenize token="order" inheritNamespaceTagName="orders" xml="true"/>
```

Give that a try.

You can find links to a couple of blog posts how to split big XML files with Camel. The links are at this page: http://camel.apache.org/articles. The 2nd is about camel-stax that is a different approach using a JAXB annotated pojo to model the data.

Also we are working on a camel-vtdxml component. It can also split big XML files using the vtd-xml library. See details at: http://camel.apache.org/vtd-xml

Comment: Hi Claus. Thanks for your help, but the inheritNamespaceTagName doesn't do anything with namespace prefixes. It just copies the namespace definitions from the parent tag. You can see this in the source: org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder#tokenizeXMLExpression

JAXB isn't performing enough. In our application we need to process 10 million orders within a few minutes.

I created a sample class: http://pastebin.com/h2GLVsHb
When you change "order" and "orders" to "foo:order"/"foo:orders" it works, but I think it should work without the namespace prefix.